# For positive operators $A$ and $B$ with $A^6=B^6$ show that $A=B$

Tags: vector-spaces, operator-theory

Since $A$ and $B$ are positive, I managed to show that $A^6$ and $B^6$ are positive.

Now, I can use the fact that there exists a unique square root of both of those and since they're equal, their roots must be equal, so $A^3=B^3$. But what now?

I'm guessing I need to show that $A^2=B^2$ somehow since then I can say

$A^3=B^3\Rightarrow AA^2=BB^2 \Rightarrow A=B$

How can I do that?

Comment: What is your definition of positive? Does it include self-adjointness?

Comment: It does. That and $(Av|v)\ge 0$

Comment: Why not using the spectral theorem, and essentially repeating the idea of the proof of existence and uniqueness of positive square root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally, let $f$ be any strictly increasing continuous function on $[0, \infty)$ and suppose $f(A) = f(B)$ (as defined by the continuous functional calculus) where $A$ and $B$ are positive operators.  $f$ has a continuous inverse function $g$ defined on $f([0,\infty))$, and since $g(f(t)) = t$ for $t \in [0,\infty)$ we have $A = g(f(A)) = g(f(B)) = B$.

Comment: Interesting. I like this generalization.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Subtracting $A^2B$ on both sides leads to $A^2(A-B) = (B^2-A^2)B$. When subtracting $B^2A$ on both sides one obtains $(A^2-B^2)A = B^2(B-A)$. Since $A,B$ are arbitrary, $B-A$ vanishes if and only if $A^2-B^2 = 0$. Then apply the roots and you are done.

Comment: Could you go a little further please? I don't really understand what I get by doing the two subtractions you suggest.

Comment: You have $A^3 = B^3$ and subtraction of $A^2B$ on both sides leads to $A^3 - A^2B = A^2A-A^2B = A^2(A-B) = B^3-A^2B = B^2B-A^2B = (B^2-A^2)B$.

Comment: No no, I understand how you did the subtraction, I just don't see how the result matters. Sorry. I think I'm missing something obvious.